# docker minio fails at start with error : "disk path full"

Tags: docker, minio

I have a docker base on minio, when it starts locally on my mac i got the following error:

```
Error: disk path full
  10: cmd/fs-v1-helpers.go:320:cmd.fsCreateFile()
   9: cmd/fs-v1.go:905:cmd.(*FSObjects).putObject()
   8: cmd/fs-v1.go:819:cmd.(*FSObjects).PutObject()
   7: cmd/config-common.go:62:cmd.saveConfig()
   6: cmd/config.go:68:cmd.saveServerConfig()
   5: cmd/config-current.go:514:cmd.newSrvConfig()
   4: cmd/config-migrate.go:2474:cmd.migrateConfigToMinioSys()
   3: cmd/config.go:181:cmd.initConfig()
   2: cmd/config.go:144:cmd.(*ConfigSys).Init()
   1: cmd/server-main.go:342:cmd.serverMain()

ERROR Unable to initialize config system: Storage reached its minimum free disk threshold.
```

print of my Disk

```
/dev/disk1     465Gi  331Gi  133Gi    72% 3236100 4291731179    0%   /
devfs          187Ki  187Ki    0Bi   100%     648          0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /home
```

How can I fix it ? should I need to configure something in minio ? 
thanks

Comment: maybe related: https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/3592